# No errors with mysqli connection indicated but my form does not populate my table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There's no error with my Mysql query connection but when I click on Submit, it does not  populate the table (articles).  I have been working for hours trying to find what I am doing wrong.

SQL injection issues will be dealt accordingly later.  Prepared statements will be made.

**articleform.php**

```
<h2>Articles</h2>
    <form action="index.php?page=articles&action=" method="post">

    <table class="admin_form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <tr>
        <td width="30%"><label for="TitreArticle">Titre</label></td>
        <td><input id="TitreArticle" type="text" name="TitreArticle" value="<?php     if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])) ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30%"><label for="AuteurArticle">Auteur</label></td>
        <td><input id="AuteurArticle" type="text" name="AuteurArticle" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['AuteurArticle'])) ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><label for="ContenuArticle">Contenu de l'article</label></td>
        <td><textarea id="ContenuArticle" name="ContenuArticle"><?php if(isset($_POST['ContenuArticle'])) ?></textarea></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td> <input type="hidden" name="dateArticle" value="" /></td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn" href="index.php">Annuler</a>
            <input type="submit"  value="Envoyer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**articles.sql.php**

```
        <?php
        include ('config/dbconnect.php');

        // INSERT
        function insertArticle( $c ){
        $TitreArticle = $AuteurArticle = $ContenuArticle = "";
        if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])){
            $TitreArticle = $_POST['TitreArticle'] ;
            $AuteurArticle = $_POST['AuteurArticle'];
            $ContenuArticle = $_POST['ContenuArticle'];
            $DateArticle = $_POST['DateArticle'];
        }

        $qryInsertArt = 'INSERT INTO articles (artTitre,artAuteur,artContenu)
                                VALUES (\''.$TitreArticle.'\',
                                       \''.$AuteurArticle.'\',
                                         \''.$ContenuArticle.'\')';


        if (!mysqli_query($c,$qryInsertArt))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($c));
      }
       echo "1 record added";

    }


        // CONTROLER //
        switch( $action ){

        case 'insert' : 
            $process = insertArticle($conn);    
            if( $process == 'ok' ) 
                header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
            else 
                $page = 'articleform';
            break;

        case 'update' : 
            $process = updateArticle( $_GET[ 'item' ] );    
            if( $process == 'ok' ) 
                header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
            else 
                $page = 'articleform';
            break;

        case 'delete' : 
            $process = deleteArticle( $_GET[ 'item' ] );    
            if( $process == 'ok' ) 
                header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
            break;
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Include 'config/dbconnect.php' Please. (The Code)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Stop worrying about the code not working, AND FIX THE REAL PROBLEM

Comment: Why are you escaping single quotes?

Comment: @fred: it's a php single-quoted string using internal single-quotes... the escapes are required.

Comment: Where do you set/get `action` parameter? You pass it in url `get` but method is submitted using `post`...

Comment: MY REAL PROBLEM AS OF NOW IS MY QUERY AND FORM.  Thank you for pointing out the SQL injection attack.  I am well aware of that.

Comment: @MarcB I've never seen that before. It's Google-Time for this 'ol boy. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM #1**

```
value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])) ?>"
```

This doesn't point to any real value. It should be

```
 value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['TitreArticle'])) echo something ?>"
```

**PROBLEM #2**

And also, is this all the code you have?

Because `updateArticle()` and `deleteArticle()` are undefined functions.

**PROBLEM #3** ***IMPORTANT***

On another note `$process = insertArticle($conn);` looks wrong because `insertArticle()` doesn't return any value.

**IMPROVEMENT**

```
$qryInsertArt = 'INSERT INTO articles (artTitre,artAuteur,artContenu)
                                VALUES (\''.$TitreArticle.'\',
                                       \''.$AuteurArticle.'\',
                                         \''.$ContenuArticle.'\')';
```

I don't see why you should escape single quotes so many times (as Fred mentioned).

```
$qryInsertArt = "INSERT INTO articles (artTitre,artAuteur,artContenu)
                                VALUES ('$TitreArticle',
                                       '$AuteurArticle',
                                         '$ContenuArticle')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention, however [as MarcB stated in a comment:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745493/no-errors-with-mysqli-connection-indicated-but-my-form-does-not-populate-my-tabl#comment31085923_20745493) "*it's a php single-quoted string using internal single-quotes... the escapes are required."*

Comment: Yes but the alternate double quotes way is a lot cleaner, readable and easier to debug. :)

Comment: The double quotes creates an error.  But you were right about Problem 1 and the my form action not being finished.

Comment: ^ That's weird! I write queries like that all the time. Also, I think Problem #3 should be a problem.

Comment: Problem #3:$conn is my mysql connection.  I am passing the mysql connection.